# How to create an opportunity and quote using Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET

Tags: c#, salesforce, force.com

I connected to salesforce and I got the auth token How can I create a opportunity and quote using Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you already try to implement anything at all? Or did you try to read docs for Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET?

Comment: Hi Hleb, I tried to  implement.I am in  a stage where I can connect and get all the Account details from salesforce.I am  very new to salesforce.It would be helpful if you refer anything that I can use to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 dynamic quote = new ExpandoObject();
      quote.Name = QuoteName;
      quote.OpportunityId = OpportunityId;

      var createQuoteResponse = await client.CreateAsync( "Quote", quote );
      quote.Id = createQuoteResponse.Id;
      if ( quote.Id != null ) {
        Console.WriteLine( "Quote  created with Opportunity Id : " + OpportunityId + " , Quote Name : " + quote.Name );
      }
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

For interacting with Salesforce you can use `ForceClient` class which provide methods for all CRUD operations with SF Objects. For creation objects you should use `CreateAsync()` method. Here are few examples:

- [Sample from Github repo of toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/master/samples/SimpleConsole/Program.cs);
- [Article with samples of using toolkit](http://www.ashishblog.com/integrating-salesforce-using-the-developerforce-toolkit-for-net/).